# How can I search the program for the highest/lowest value in java?

Tags: arrays, hashmap, max, min

I have a program that currently takes an input from the user, stores it in a 1D array which is further stored in a HashMap and finally printed onto a text file. I want to add a method that can read through these different inputs and determine which one contains the largest number for a specific subject. EX:

```
          GamesPlayed Goals Assists  Points  Saves  ShotsTaken
Player1   32           5      12       9       3       8
Player2   14           2       7       3       0       6
Player3   34          13      10      26      14      19
Player4   3            0       1       0       2       3
Player5   8            4       6       7       5       9
```

Expected Results(if Highest number of Goals made is searched): "13 goals by Player3"

The program should ask the user what stat (goals, score, saves, etc) they want to search for and the program should give either the highest value and the player or the lowest.

My initial plan was to search the arrays in the HashMap, then depending on user input check the index of the array, however to be able to print the data onto the .txt file correctly without old data getting in the way i have to clear the HashMap (and using the array is useless as it is just overwritten with a new input)

This is the method where all the data is received and printed.

```java
void addData() {
        boolean cont;

        do try {
            System.out.println("Player First Name: ");
            String firstName = scan.nextLine() + " ";

            System.out.println("Player Last Name: ");
            String lastName = scan.nextLine();

            String fullName = firstName.concat(lastName);

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Games Played: ");
            int gamesPlayed = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Goals Made: ");
            int goals = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Assists Made: ");
            int assists = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Points Scored: ");
            int points = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Saves Made: ");
            int saves = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter Number of Shots Made: ");
            int shotsOnGoal = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

            int[] data = {gamesPlayed, goals, assists, points, saves, shotsOnGoal};
            String dataString = Arrays.toString(data);

            map.put(fullName, dataString);
            out.write("==================================\n");
            out.write(String.valueOf(map));
            out.flush();
            map.clear();
            out.newLine();

            cont = false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Enter Valid Input");
            cont = true;
        } while (cont);
        
    }
```

Comment: Why not seek all the map accumulating the value and the name of the greatest or the lowest stats entered? You can make some changes in order to optimize your search. Like keep the data inside arrays instead of convert into a string. With strings you will be forced to split the at the time of the seek.

Comment: That is what i tried first but because of how the data was printing(old data entangled with new data) i had to clear the map after each print. so when i tried searching for the values they would no longer exist

Comment: What i am trying now is to instead of printing the map itself onto the file, i print the format, leaving the HashMap and a simple storage container for my values. `out.write("{" + fullName + "=[" + Arrays.toString(data) + "]}");`

Comment: Hi Newb_pro.. Do you know the Observable design pattern, I'm not sure, but I think that you can create some data structure to make your program deal with yor problem in a more elegant way.

The strategy cabe be, one observer for skill and at the end of each input all of them are updated.

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer

Comment: I know that is not specifically your approach but take a look at these approach:

https://github.com/filipemarruda/playerStatsBoard

start from the tests to understand the pattern's use